# How do I compare the current time with time saved in database using django?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views

I'm making a simple Timetable web app to display current lecture ad subject after fetching the device time and match it with django database time. My database is having columns for **Day, Time and Subject**.
General Sql query be like

```
SELECT * FROM tablename 
WHERE timecolumn >= '12:00'
AND Daycolumn = 'Monday'
```

**I am very new to django I only figure out to display the data like that but unable to understand about comparing it and then only display.**

```
{% for subject in subjects %}
{{ subject }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asuming your model is something like:

```
from djago.db import models

class Schedule(models.Model):
    day_of_week = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    time = models.TimeField()
    ...
```

You can query the table with the following code:

```
from datetime import date

subjects = Schedule.objects.filter(day_of_week="Monday", time__gte=time(12, 0, 0))
```

You just then need to get the subjects variable into the template context.